Missing kernel logs for system crash
I'm using Debian 12.2 as a headless server, installed on a laptop (Dell Latitude E5450, i5 CPU) with external SSD (always plugged in).
I noticed that I couldn't connect to the server in the evening and when I checked the laptop it was still on, but was showing me strange errors on screen and I didn't have access to run commands. SSH also didn't work, although ping to the machine did work.
I see in the logs the time of the crash (approximately) but it's missing a lot of info on how it crashed. Notice that it happened after 10:30 with this line "boot 669a773756934f8080b5a53aeabf2b38" that has no timestamp.
I noticed the problem and forced-rebooted at 20:31
How can I get more in-depth logs to find the root cause?
I ran:
sudo journalctl --system --since "2024-06-02 10:26:00"

Output:
Jun 02 10:26:11 umbrel dhclient[610]: RCV: Advertise message on eno1 from fe80::b2be:76ff:fe22:39b5.
Jun 02 10:26:37 umbrel umbreld[850]: [apprepository] Checking for update for https://github.com/getumbrel/umbrel-apps.g>
Jun 02 10:26:38 umbrel umbreld[850]: [apprepository] https://github.com/getumbrel/umbrel-apps.git is already up to date
Jun 02 10:28:05 umbrel dhclient[610]: XMT: Solicit on eno1, interval 121800ms.
Jun 02 10:28:05 umbrel dhclient[610]: RCV: Advertise message on eno1 from fe80::b2be:76ff:fe22:39b5.
Jun 02 10:30:07 umbrel dhclient[610]: XMT: Solicit on eno1, interval 118670ms.
Jun 02 10:30:07 umbrel dhclient[610]: RCV: Advertise message on eno1 from fe80::b2be:76ff:fe22:39b5.
-- Boot 669a773756934f8080b5a53aeabf2b38 --
Jun 02 20:31:45 umbrel kernel: microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0x2f, date = 2019-11-12
Jun 02 20:31:45 umbrel kernel: Linux version 6.1.0-21-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc-12 (Debian 12.2.0-14)

UPDATE:
The problem happened again. But this time I was able to run commands via SSH and only noticed the services aren't working later at around 12:00, so this doesn't even make sense, because the system was basically responding to my commands for 3 hours until I noticed that the services running on it stopped working. Yet there are no logs for that time the terminal was responding to me (via SSH).
Why does it stop logging with that "boot" line? I understand it's the boot number as shown in the output for the command "sudo journalctl --list-boots"
But how can I troubleshoot this problem? Seems like I'm missing log info, no?
Jun 03 05:12:01 umbrel kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#8 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD IN
Jun 03 05:12:01 umbrel kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#8 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 8f db 54 ea 00 01 00 00
-- Boot 13a89a39a867489dbd59b2f97661691b --
Jun 03 12:20:50 umbrel kernel: microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0x2f, date = 2019-11-12


Some cases that put the CPU to death before anything gets logged (especially on low budget systems) : Power interruption; CPU Overheating, GPU Power/Overheating, etc. Physical causes, not software.  Logs leading up to a crash: sudo journalctl  -b -1 -ex

Using this command shows me the same logs that I posted. There's just nothing after that 10:30 timestamp.
The server was not under load during that time, it was relatively idle.
The laptop is a Dell Latitude E5450 with i5 CPU, not so low budget.
How would I check for hardware failure causes, if that's the real cause?

Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story. This is a Question and Answer site, not a conversation site. If you have an update, [edit] your Question.  If you have a new question, see  [Ask].
